# Drupal, Ubercart: how can I get the order printable version programmatically?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, ubercart

I need to generate a pdf from Ubecarts orders. I know how to access to the printable versions of orders from my browser: i.e. "admin/store/orders/45/invoice/print"

However, I was wondering how to access to the page from php, maybe using ubercart apis ?

What I need is the equivalent of node_view, for orders (which is not a node).

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is an actual API for it, but you could use [`uc_order_load_invoice`](http://api.lullabot.com/uc_order_load_invoice), the order object you need can be generated by the [`uc_order_load`](http://api.lullabot.com/uc_order_load) function.

Comment: great, thanks: $invoice = uc_order_load_invoice(uc_order_load(45));